# Html in browser different than the one requested in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
page = requests.get("https://sky.lea.moe/stats/PapaGordsmack/", headers=headers)
html_contents = page.text
print(html_contents)
```

I am trying to webscrape from sky.lea.moe website for a specific user, but when I request the html and print it, it is different than the one shown in browser(on chrome, viewing page source).

The one I get is: https://pastebin.com/91zRw3vP
Analyzing this one, it is something about checking browser and redirecting. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: What does "it is something about checking browser and redirecting" mean? Do you know what the problem is? Are you sure the HTML is not modified by JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers indeed do more than just download a webpage. They also download additional resources, parse style and things like that. To scrape a webpage it is advised to use a scraping library like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) that does all these things for you and provide a complete library to easily extract information from these pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is cloudflare's anti-dos protection, and it is effective at stopping scraping. A JS script will usually redirect you after a few seconds.

Something like [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/) is probably your best option for getting around it, though you might be able to scrape the JS file and get the URL to redirect. You could also try spoofing your referrer to be this page, so it goes to the correct one.